Connecting an energy meter with 6 CTs?

I want to install an energy meter to monitor the energy consumption of a transformer. The secondary side of this transformer is a parallel circuit, making it impossible to connect three current transformers (CTs) to the three phases of the secondary side.
The challenge is that I need to measure six points, which requires six current transformers.
Is it possible to connect two current transformers to a single input of the energy meter?

What kind of circuit is it?

Welcome! Please draw a schematic.

It is a 20 kV/410 V transformer with a secondary current of 225.3 A, supplying two protection panels with circuit breakers inside. There are three phase wires and a neutral going to each panel.

how can i add a schematic on this platform ?

Click on Edit, then click on the schematic symbol. You can draw it from there.

I added a schematic

"impossible to connect three current transformers (CTs) to the three phases of the secondary side" Due to mechanical constraints?

exactly we cannot access the three phases that come directly out of the transformer

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
